# jQuery Allow a single click but disallow a double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I originally wanted a submit to take place on a single click event:

```
    $("#booking_Form #submit_Booking").bind("click", function(event){.....
```

I then found (obviously) that a double click led to a duplicate submission.

So I tried capturing and suppressing this with:

```
    $("#booking_Form #submit_Booking").bind("dblclick", function(event){
          return false;
    });
```

But the single click event still fired twice.

Am I correct it thinking that if it is imperative that a double click does not submit twice that I must change the single click event to a double click event.

Or is there some global way to switch off double clicks.

Comment: would disabling the button after the single click solve your problem?

Comment: try adding a delay on the event. In that way you can flush the second event and only submit once. I done this with KeyUp event so that users can type a few keys (2~3) before it runs the ajax request.

Comment: I think Scott has the right idea. JQuery's own documentation states it's inadvisable to bind event handlers to both single and double-click events as the results are unpredictable.  Instead, disabling the button as Scott recommended should work.

Comment: @ScottSimpson, it might but then again with JS events it might not because the second click could happen before the code disables the button.

Comment: yes disabling it would indeed however it is not an input type="submit" button. I am unsure if I can stop a second click on my bespoke button once the first is fired?

Comment: yes agreed it is a bad idea to have both single and double click events on a single selector.  So I have to do setTimeout to encapsulate the ajax inside the function. ? how to a kill off / flush the second or subsequent clicks? @Nick.T

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `.one()`. That way all subsequent clicks will do nothing

```
$("#booking_Form #submit_Booking").one("click", function(event) {
    //do something
});
```

Link: http://api.jquery.com/one/

EDIT:
If you want to use `.one()`, how about doing something like this...

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#b1").one("click", function(e){
        ajaxFunction();
     });   

    function ajaxFunction(){
         $("#b1").one("click", function(e){
             ajaxFunction()
         });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/", //use actual URL
            success: function(data){
               //do something    
            }
        });           
    }
});​
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/BKqm9/13/

Comment: OK this is looking good I have not come across one before. However reading the comments to the one documentation it does not appear that there is a method to reset the one once the ajax is completed. And the whole objective is to avoid a refresh. Any thoughts as to how one can be reset.

Comment: Sure, I have made an edit to my initial post.  I hope it helps!

Comment: Apologies for not quite getting this. I really like the idea of using the .one - I am calling it a pseudo bind - but I don't see where you managed to reset it. Is it the bit where the function calls itself and if so I would love to know how that has the desired effect.

Comment: No worries! Okay, so we initially bind `.one()` to `$("#b1")` and have it call `ajaxFunction`.  It is in the `ajaxFuntion` function where we "reset" the bind. As you can see, I bind`.one()` to `$("#b1")` again before making the ajax call.  This is because the `.one()` runs once and ONLY once. By binding `.one()` again, we are creating a loop, so the button click event will always run once.

Comment: OK That's very neat. Thank you for taking the time to explain that.

Answer (score 4):

Just disable your input in the click handler, so the user cannot click a second time, you will enable it again when you finish the logic in your click handler. So you can do as follows:

```
$("#booking_Form #submit_Booking").bind("click", function(event){
   $(this).attr('disabled','true');
   ...
   ...
   var btn = $(this);
   $.ajax('someurl.php',{success: function(){
          ...
          ...
          btn.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
   })
}
```

Comment: Yes I can see that except that I not using a type="submit" button. Because I am using an ajax call inside the function instead of the form's submit function.

Comment: It's the same code for an ajax function, just re-enable the button on the success callback of the ajax call. I've updated my answer with an ajax example.

Comment: OK I had not realised that disabled could be applied in this way. I only previously applied this to form submit buttons. So that's excellent learning that and much easier than messing around with dblclick. Only I note that I could not get removeattr to work used removeAttr instead.

Comment: Oh dear - I can't accept both answers! I like the .one approach. However this is more conventional and easier to follow. I have therfore given votes to both.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in a closure and use a dirty flag variable. (closure so the flag isn't global)

```
(function(){
    var dirtyFlag = false;
    $('#clicker').click(function(){
        if (dirtyFlag) return;
        dirtyFlag = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('clean and proceeding');
            dirtyFlag = false;
        }, 500);
    });
})();​
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wZPVQ/). Since disabling the button isn't an option this is IMO the cleanest and simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the queuing method, try something like this : (just a mockup)

```
$('<div>').clearQueue('buttonQueue');

$("#booking_Form #submit_Booking").bind("click", function(event) {
    $('<div>').clearQueue('buttonQueue');
    $('<div>').queue('buttonQueue', myFunctionHere());
});
```

putting this in the DocumentReady function should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
$("#booking_Form #submit_Booking").bind("click", function(e) {

    // custom handling here
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}​
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Before Your logic execute you can disable your button after one click and after executing your code you can enable your button click event. It's simple-

```
$("#saveOrder").attr("disabled", true);
```

Your logic goes here

```
$("#saveOrder").attr("disabled", false);
```