# How to apply single click for future element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to apply jquery single click for future elements? Please refer my code below

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.testClass', testfunction);
```

I want to allow only single click for this code. How can i do it?

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Allow a single click but disallow a double click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686419/jquery-allow-a-single-click-but-disallow-a-double-click)

Comment: Do you really want to only accept a single click on only the first `testClass`, or once per element with `class="textClass"`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking imho

Comment: If you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 3):

Use [**one()**](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$(document.body).one('click', '.testClass', testfunction);
```

This will fire **one** click event for **all** `.testClass` elements.

If you want to fire **one** click event **per** `.testClass`, manually track if an element is clicked with `data-*` attributes

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.testClass', testfunction);

function testfunction(){
    if($(this).data('clicked')) return;
    $(this).data('clicked', 1);
    /* rest of logic there*/
}
```

Comment: +one for proving the existence of a delegated version of `one` :) Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bwqxgp7s/

Comment: Be aware, this would fire only once for all `.testClass` elements, not once **for each** `.testClass` element. I'm not sure this is expected behaviour. This could be the expected behaviour instead: http://jsfiddle.net/bwqxgp7s/1/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I was going to respond about the overload you quoted but the answer was deleted

Comment: @AmmarCSE Your workaround doesn't fix it because event is delegated to body level

Comment: @A.Wolff, I never thought of that. Ive included namespaced events. Now is the workaround correct?

Comment: @AmmarCSE No because `$(this).off('click.once');` will removed namespaced click event to specific `.testClass` element **but** you are binding event to body level. If class is used just for hanlding event and for some reason you (OP) doesn't want to add extra class, then simplest workaround is to remove class: http://jsfiddle.net/bwqxgp7s/2/

Comment: @A.Wolff, first, thanks for pointing out my mistake! I learned something new. Second, I went with a more manual solution in case that class has other effects or styles

Comment: @AmmarCSE I edited answer, i didn't know method `hasAttr()`?! EDIT: ya, doesn't exist indeed  PS: and ya good point using `data`, seems more relevant than using a class or something else

Comment: @A.Wolff, I dont know how I thought that method exists...thanks again :)

Comment: @AmmarCSE - Thanks a lot, Your code is solved my problem